# Delphi BDE with connection to Oracle access violation

Tags: oracle, delphi, blob, delphi-xe7, bde

I'm searching for a bug in a big legacy product. The end user only reports a program crash (no error messages).
When I start the program with attached debugger I get this:

```
Im Projekt XXXXX.exe ist eine Exception der Klasse $C0000005 mit der Meldung 'access violation at 0x00000000: read of address 0x00000000' aufgetreten.
```

When I look at the stack trace the error happened here:

```
procedure TQuery.FreeStatement;
var
  Result: DbiResult;
begin
  if StmtHandle <> nil then
  begin
    Result := DbiQFree(FStmtHandle);
    if not (csDestroying in ComponentState) then
      Check(Result);
  end;
end;
```

The AV happens at the `Result := DbiQFree(FStmtHandle);` line.

It is triggered by a call to `TQuery.Close`.
The `TQuery` object in question is used for `Select` statements.
I can't figure out where the nil pointer is located.
I already used FastMM4 with FullDebugMode to find if there is any use after free or other stuff. But FastMM4 don't reports anything erroneous.
I also recompiled the Project with enabled madExcept but madExcept also can't catch the error (program simply closes when no Debugger is connected).

I attached an OnDisconnect and OnConnect event handler to the `TDatabase` object. At the time of the error the connection is not disconnected according to the events.

Does anyone have an idea where the error can be located? Also any software or debugging tip to get closer to the potential erroneous pice of code is helpful ;-)

Comment: The nil check on `StmtHandle` doesn't protect against `FStmtHandle` being nil. Make sure there is not a bad SQL statement - sometimes if the BDE fails to parse a statement it can leave things in a odd state.

Comment: I've added an Debug Eval Expression on `TQuery.QueryChanged` and printed out `SQL.Text`. The last query I can see before the exception occures are correct queries. Syntactically correct and I can fire it against the Database without an error. Do you have any other idea what could gone wrong here?

Comment: An address that low indicates that you're accessing a null pointer. It's impossible to tell where it's happening based on a single snippet of code that is totally out of context. The issue clearly isn't in the code that you've posted, but is somewhere in the code before it got to that point. Without a [mre], we can't debug this, but you can. Set breakpoints in your code further up the callstack, where it is in your own code, and single-step through the code until the exception occurs. Then set a breakpoint on that line, and check the value of variables when it is hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Statement executed by the TQuery Object prior to the Close call was an `Select * ...` statement. The Query returned several Columns one of them was a RAW aka BLOB Column. The Content of the Columns was maybe too big to handle it.  After reviewing the Code and checking that the RAW Column Data is not used at all instead the query is only used to check if there is data in the Table. I changed the Query to `Select 1 ...` the Problem is fixed. So, for everyone having same strange error. Check the resulting data set for RAW columns. Even when the returned Row has a NULL Value in the given Column.